# How to retrieve a value that is entered on localhost to make a condition

Tags: php, cakephp

I baked something on cake bake and entering values on local host in that application. The name of the value that i want to retrieve for php script is temperature. how can i get that value?

Here is the some information laying behind the application:

[useDbConfig] => default

```
[useTable] => temperature_readings
[id] => 32
[data] => Array
    (
        [TemperatureReading] => Array
            (
                [temperature] => 15
                [location_id] => 5
                [created] => 1437572170
                [id] => 32
```

that temperature value, which is 15, is the variable that i want to use in php script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access temperature like this:

```
$temperature = $array['data']['TemperatureReading']['temperature'];
echo $temperature; //Returns 15
```

Comment: Thanks for help @Daan